# How can I make a WPF ContextMenu automatically select the first item when it's opened?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I'm opening a ContextMenu when a user hits a short-cut key (by changing its IsOpen property to true). But when it opens, no item is selected. How can I make the first item be selected, so that the user doesn't have to press the down-arrow to reach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item">
        <ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
                <MenuItem Click="some_event" Header="Qwerty"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

And in code-behind:

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
    (contextMenu.Items[0] as MenuItem).Focus();
}
```

Comment: Sadly this only works, if the items are added explictly as `MenuItem`s. If items are added via binding, then `contextMenu.Items` will return the (view)models used for populating the ContextMenu - without access to the actual `MenuItem` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which control ( Datagrid, ListView or whatever) you are intending to select. However, the very first thing you need to check is that whether or not your control support  `KeyPress` event. If it support, then try to attach handler for the `KeyPress` and write logic to check the required key and select item accordingly.

You can check a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404681/move-focus-to-next-cell-on-enter-key-press-in-wpf-datagrid) which has the implementation on how to select data grid cell/row based on Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work for dynamic context menus.

**1. Create a custom context menu that uses a custom menu item - instead of the default `MenuItem` class.**

For this to work we need to custom classes, `MyContextMenu` and `MyMenuItem`:

**MyContextMenu:**

```
public class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    private object _currentItem;

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        bool ret = (item is MyMenuItem) || (item is Separator);
        if (!ret)
        {
            _currentItem = item;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        object currentItem = _currentItem;
        _currentItem = null;

        if (UsesItemContainerTemplate)
        {
            DataTemplate itemContainerTemplate = ItemContainerTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(currentItem, this);
            if (itemContainerTemplate != null)
            {
                object itemContainer = itemContainerTemplate.LoadContent();
                if (itemContainer is MyMenuItem || itemContainer is Separator)
                {
                    return itemContainer as DependencyObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ImplementationException("InvalidItemContainer!");
                }
            }
        }

        return new MyMenuItem();
    }
}
```

**MyMenuItem:**

```
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public MyMenuItem()
    {

    }
    private object _currentItem;

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        bool ret = (item is MyMenuItem) || (item is Separator);
        if (!ret)
        {
            _currentItem = item;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        object currentItem = _currentItem;
        _currentItem = null;

        if (UsesItemContainerTemplate)
        {
            DataTemplate itemContainerTemplate = ItemContainerTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(currentItem, this);
            if (itemContainerTemplate != null)
            {
                object itemContainer = itemContainerTemplate.LoadContent();
                if (itemContainer is MyMenuItem || itemContainer is Separator)
                {
                    return itemContainer as DependencyObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ImplementationException("InvalidItemContainer!");
                }
            }
        }

        return new MyMenuItem();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsManuallyFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsManuallyFocused), typeof(bool), typeof(MyMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), IsManuallyFocusedChanged));

    private static void IsManuallyFocusedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (MyMenuItem)d;
        if (item.IsManuallyFocused) item.Focus();
    }

    public bool IsManuallyFocused
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsManuallyFocusedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsManuallyFocusedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Both classes contain two identical overrides as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102174/how-can-i-make-contextmenu-use-my-custom-menuitem-class). Admittedly, this is somewhat of a hack, because it relies on correctly imitating internal code.

Now, when creating the context menu, use the new class, `MyContextMenu`.

The second class, `MyMenuItem`, has an additional `DependencyProperty` that we will use in a `DataTrigger` later on. As you can see in `IsManuallyFocusedChanged`, if `IsManuallyFocused` is set to `true`, the `Focus()` method is called for the item.

Note: The actual value of `MyMenuItem.IsManuallyFocused` is never read, we're just using the property as a mechanism for binding that allows us to invoke a method.

**2. Adapt styles to target the new type ´MyMenuItem`.**

Apart from the additional trigger we're adding here, be sure to change all `TargetType` specifications in your styles to the new menu item type.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type menuControls:MyMenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type menuControls:MyMenuItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsManuallyFocused}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsManuallyFocused" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The `DataTrigger` above assumes that the menu items are bound to a class (not further described here) that contains a property ´IsManuallyFocused`including change notifications, either using`INotifyPropertyChanged`or a`DependencyProperty`.

Note: In this example the properties have the same name, but they could be named differently; `DataTrigger.Binding` must reference the property on the source class, while `Setter.Property` must reference the property on the new menu item class, `MyMenuItem`.

**3. Focus the desired element.**

Assuming you have access to the context menu's source items, select the designated item an simply set `IsManuallyFocused` to `true`.

Due to the `DataTrigger`, this change will be "forwarded" to the property of the new menu item class where the change handler (``) will set the focus on the bound menu item.

**Comments**

While this works fine and implementing a custom menu item and context menu class may come in handy further down the road, especially the "mis-use" of the `IsManuallyFocused` dependency property seams complicated. If there is a better way, I'd appreciated another - better - answer.