# How can I make ContextMenu use my custom MenuItem class?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm working on a C# desktop app and am looking for a way to programmatically highlight/select a `MenuItem`, I came across this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71115000/4247806

That looks ok, but my menu is populated by binding `ItemsSource` to a list of `ICommand` classes, and not explicitly in Xaml markup. So WPF creates the required `MenuItem` instances behind-the-scenes. *How can I make ContextMenu use my custom MenuItem class?*

During previous work on a custom `DataGrid` I stumbled across a `GetContainerForItemOverride` method that the `ContextMenu` class has as well. This lead me to this approach:

```
public class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyMenuItem();
    }
}

public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    public MyMenuItem()
    {
        
    }

    public new bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get => base.IsHighlighted;
        set => base.IsHighlighted = value;
    }
}
```

However, I would like to exactly mimick/imitate the original behavior, except that I need a `MyMenuItem` instance. Looking at the implementation of `ContextMenu.GetContainerForItemOverride` I've found this:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    object currentItem = _currentItem;
    _currentItem = null;
    if (UsesItemContainerTemplate)
    {
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = ItemContainerTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(currentItem, this);
        if (dataTemplate != null)
        {
            object obj = dataTemplate.LoadContent();
            if (obj is MenuItem || obj is Separator)
            {
                return obj as DependencyObject;
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get("InvalidItemContainer", GetType().Name, typeof(MenuItem).Name, typeof(Separator).Name, obj));
        }
    }

    return new MenuItem();
}
```

I can't reproduce this behavior due to the `private object _currentItem` being used. If I ignore this, in which scenarios could this cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/MenuBase.cs,9f321165c9672463), you'll see that the private field `_currentItem` is only used in two methods so you could easily replicate this code in your custom `MyContextMenu` and simply change type from `MenuItem` to `MyMenuItem` if that's what you want:

```
private object _currentItem;

protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    bool ret = (item is MenuItem) || (item is Separator);
    if (!ret)
    {
        _currentItem = item;
    }

    return ret;
}

protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    object currentItem = _currentItem;
    _currentItem = null;

    if (UsesItemContainerTemplate)
    {
        DataTemplate itemContainerTemplate = ItemContainerTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(currentItem, this);
        if (itemContainerTemplate != null)
        {
            object itemContainer = itemContainerTemplate.LoadContent();
            if (itemContainer is MenuItem || itemContainer is Separator)
            {
                return itemContainer as DependencyObject;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidItemContainer, this.GetType().Name, typeof(MenuItem).Name, typeof(Separator).Name, itemContainer));
            }
        }
    }

    return new MenuItem();
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but be sure to update any ´Style` definitions to use the new TargetType and also implement the above overrides for the derived `MenuItem` class as well - that will be needed for submenus.

Comment: Again, this was great, but now the default context menu for text boxes (when text is selected) throws an exception, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75735525/4247806) - any ideas?